# How to take multiple inputs on Twilio-Whatsapp?

Tags: python, flask, twilio, webhooks

I'm using Twilio with Whatsapp, I want to take multiple inputs from users on Whatsapp but I am only able to get the first input.
My first input is usually "hello" from user
then my query
and the second input I want

````
```
@app.route("/allr", methods=['POST'])
def start():
    phonestring = request.form["From"]
    phonenumber = int(re.search(r'\d+', phonestring).group(0))
    print(phonenumber)
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg1 = request.form.get('Body') #usually hello or something to     initialize
    l1 = (db.search(User.Phone == phonenumber))
    if len(l1)!=0:
        aj=l1[0]
        print(aj['Preference'])
        pref=aj['Preference']
        print("Done")

        resp.message("{} News".format(pref))
    else:

        resp.message("Which updates would you like?\n1.National\n2.Regional")

        pref = request.form.get('Body') # I need input but I get it as          hello(the input above)
        print(pref)
        resp.message("You selected: {}".format(pref))
        Item3 = {'Phone': phonenumber, 'Preference': pref}
        db.insert(Item3)

    return str(resp)
    ```
````

Expected: Regional/National
What I get: Hello

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It appears that when you receive the user's first message that you are not storing anything in the database. So, when you receive their second message, you look up the user by phone number but still don't find anything.

Also, it sounds like you are expecting to receive more than one message within this piece of code. Each webhook request from Twilio corresponds to one incoming message. If you are looking for the response to the second message, it will be in a second webhook.